# Debian laptop suspends periodically

Tags: debian, power-management, laptop

My Debian laptop (current release: testing) today started to suspend periodically for some unknown reason. It happens either I'm trying to type something, use mouse or make any other activity.

What I tried to do:

- disable suspending settings in `gnome-power-manager` schema, but it continues to work in the same manner;
- check logs in `/var/logs/pm-suspend.log` (is empty) `/var/logs/pm-powersave.log` (is not empty, but I didn't understand anything);
- compare `dmesg` logs before and after suspending but I didn't found any hint why this could be caused.

I still believe it is software problem, but I have no idea how to identify **what** (or which one process) causes laptop to sleep. So any hints how the problem can be identified and fixed are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Read this

Suspend and hibernate configuration in Debian Jessie

You may get hibernation working out of the box (even without uswsusp), provided that you have a swap partition big enough to hold an image of the system.

It can sometimes be convenient to have a laptop first "Suspend" to RAM, for quick wake-up -- but then automatically save RAM to disk, and power off. This combination of suspend-then-hibernate has been dubbed "Suspend Sedation" by Microsoft. For information of how to enable such behaviour with systemd, see: SystemdSuspendSedation.

than:

https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdSuspendSedation